# Chat with option to send file

Tags: java, c, tcp

I would like to create a simple TCP chat with option to send files.
Sending messages to other clients works, but sending files doesn't work. My chat sends only few bytes of file.

Chat works like: Server starts up and wait for clients, Clients connect to server and they can send messages to other clients through the server. I would like to allow to the same with files.

Server is wrote in C, and Client is wrote in Java (I had guidelines like that).

Server:

```
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) {
        sd = client_socket[i]; 

        memset(buffer, 0, 10000);
        if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds)) {
            if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 1024)) == 0) {
                getpeername(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen); 
                printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" , 
                    inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port)); 



                close( sd ); 
                client_socket[i] = 0; 
            } 
            else {
                // When message "start" arrived download the file and send it back to other clients
                if (strcmp(buffer, "start") == 0) {
                    uint8_t buff[10000];
                    // Read chunks of file
                    while (read( sd , buff, sizeof(buff)) > 0) {

                        // Sending chunks of file to other clients
                        for(j=0; j<max_clients; j++) {
                            int outSock = client_socket[j];
                            if(outSock != master_socket && outSock != sd) {
                                send(outSock , buff , sizeof(buff) , 0 ); 
                            }
                    }

                    }
                } else {

                    buffer[valread] = '\0'; 
                    for(j=0; j<max_clients; j++) {
                        int outSock = client_socket[j];
                        if(outSock != master_socket && outSock != sd) {
                            send(outSock , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 ); 
                        }
                    }

                }

            } 
        } 
    }
```

Client:

```
@FXML
void sendFile(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    // Send "start" message to let server know that I'm going to send a file
    out.println("start");
    out.flush();

    try {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        //Get socket's output stream
        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        //Read File Contents into contents array
        byte[] contents;
        long fileLength = file.length();
        long current = 0;

        while(current!=fileLength){
            int size = 10000;
            if(fileLength - current >= size)
                current += size;
            else{
                size = (int)(fileLength - current);
                current = fileLength;
            }
            contents = new byte[size];
            bis.read(contents, 0, size);
            os.write(contents);
            System.out.print("Sending file ... "+(current*100)/fileLength+"% complete!");
        }

        os.flush();
        System.out.println("File sent successfully!");

    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}

public ChatWindowController() {

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 54000);
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    while(isRunning) {
                        if (ta_display != null) {
                            String message = inFromServer.readLine();
                            if (!isDownloadingFile) {
                                System.out.println(message);
                                ta_display.appendText(message + '\n');

                                if (message.equals("start")) {
                                    isDownloadingFile = true;
                                }
                            } else {

                                byte[] contents = new byte[10000];

                                //Initialize the FileOutputStream to the output file's full path.
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/example/test.png");
                                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                                InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

                                //No of bytes read in one read() call
                                int bytesRead = 0;

                                while((bytesRead=is.read(contents))!=-1)
                                    bos.write(contents, 0, bytesRead);

                                bos.flush();

                                System.out.println("File saved successfully!");

                            }
                        }

                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I click button sendFile method is called, then I choose file and I want to send this file, and with other clients download it.

Comment: OK, so, did you isolate the problem, identifying the part of your code which is causing the problem? Did you run into any error messages in your log? Please make sure you do your due diligence before asking for help.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. When I send a file, other clients get only a few bytes of this file.

Comment: *"I'm not getting any errors. .. `} catch(Exception e) { }`"* With that code, you have no way of **knowing** if there were errors. Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a similar example for chatting at https://github.com/foreverpersist/socket/blob/master/chatroom.c.

File transferring is implemented by P2P

1. Server tells `<IP:PORT>`s of sender and receiver to each other.
2. Sender and receiver connect to each other directly.
3. Sender sends file to receiver.
4. Sender and receiver close the connection.

As what happens in your project, when transferring files with path `Sender -> Server -> Receiver`, the content of large files may be incomplete if you don't deal carefully. So, I just transfer files with path `Sender -> Receiver`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there is a bug on the server when receiving the file:

```
//client sends 10000 bytes of data in chunks of unknown size

//receive one chunk of unknown size
while (read( sd , buff, sizeof(buff)) > 0) {
    for(j=0; j<max_clients; j++) {
        int outSock = client_socket[j];
        if(outSock != master_socket && outSock != sd) {
            // Send 10000 bytes aka the received chunk and whatever else is in the buffer to all clients
            send(outSock , buff , sizeof(buff) , 0 ); 
        }
    }
```

You need to either receive all the data first and then send it to the clients, or only send the size of the chunk many bytes, like in the File writer in the client or as follows:

```
int chunk = 0;
while ((chunk = read( sd , buff, sizeof(buff))) > 0) {
    ...
    send(outSock , buff , chunk , 0);
```

Also Im not certain if the Client file writing code works, you should ensure that no following messages are written to file accidently.

Comment: I tried that, and sent file on the client side has only 20kb instead of about 1mb.

Comment: Have you checked how much data is received by the server? And are these 20kb identical to the first 20kb of the sent file?

Comment: When I try to print size of chunks nothing is displayed.

Comment: That can be caused by all kinds of issues, either A) get the output to display, maybe by asking a new question or B) find another way to get messages from the server directly, maybe by logging to a file, debugging, sending debug messages on another networkport, etc....